# SQL query for replacing null values in all columns of a row with values taken from rows of another table with matching ID

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

for example , let us say i have a table A which looks like this

| ID | Country | Name | EmployeeCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 456 | NULL | DAN | 2258 |

and then i have another table B which looks like this

| ID | Country | Name | EmployeeCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | US | MARY | 3247 |
| 456 | GERMANY | JOHN | 1228 |

I would like the resulting table to look like this

| ID | Country | Name | EmployeeCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | US | MARY | 3247 |
| 456 | GERMANY | DAN | 2258 |

In other words, keep the information that is present in table A and replace all Null values for ALL columns (in the example above i wrote just 3 columns for the sake of simplicity, the actual number of columns I need to work on is much higher) in table A from rows in table B which have matching ID. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`coalesce`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#coalesce):

`coalesce(value1, value2[, ...])` - Returns the first non-null value in the argument list. Like a `CASE` expression, arguments are only evaluated if necessary.

Something like:

```sql
SELECT a.ID
    , coalesce(a.Country, b.Country)
    , coalesce(a.Name, b.Name)
    , coalesce(a.EmployeeCode, b.EmployeeCode)
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b on a.ID = b.ID
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the below code should do what you want :

```
Select 
       A.ID
       ,isnull(A.Country,B.Country)
       ,isnull(A.Name,B.Name)
       ,isnull(A.EmployeeCode,B.EmployeeCode)
from table1 A
left join table2 B
on A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: The post was tagged with amazon-athena